# How to configure .htaccess for a Laravel API app which is hosted on a subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I have a domain `mydomain.com` and a nginx space to host my website. The URL address `mydomain.com` is already in use and I don't want to buy another domain, so I created a subdomain `myapp.mydomain.com`. Then I created a laravel API app `myapp` for testing purposes and uploaded the code into `/mydomain_com/myapp` folder via a FTP client.

The problem now is I have to configure my `.htaccess` accordingly so the the app can run correctly.

At the current state, the homepage route `/` is working fine, but everything else is not working.

**\mydomain_com\myapp.env:**

```
...
APP_NAME=myapp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:U4v....
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://myapp.mydomain.com
...
```

**My routes are:**
[image: Laravel API app routes]

**\mydomain_com\myapp\routes\web.php**

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/aaa', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**\mydomain_com\myapp\routes\api.php**

```php
Route::apiResource('os', OsController::class);
```

Now, when I go to `https://myapp.mydomain.com` I get this:

[image: homepage route]

However when I try to visit `https://myapp.mydomain.com/aaa` and `https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/os`, I get this error ↓

[image: /aaa route]

**Can You pls tell me what's the problem with my `\mydomain_com\myapp\.htaccess` ↓ ? Why is the homepage only working?**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using the htaccess which is already with the laravel and Im posting it below, it works fine with me

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Also check if the mod_rewrite is enabled in your server, if you are using ubuntu and apache2 server enable the mod_rewrite using the command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Kindly refer : [Enable mod_rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but after I replaced my code with your code and try to go to my homepage `https://myapp.mydomain.com`, the browser will show this ERROR: `Missing index page or access denied!`. Do You know why?

Comment: Where you put the htaccess file, in the root or inside the public folder, 
If you put it in the root of the project create an index.php file (if not exist) add the following `include 'public/index.php';`

Comment: So, i removed the `.htaccess` from the project root, and now I only have the `.htaccess` within the `public` folder. I created the `index.php` with your code in the project root → Now the homepage is working OK, but other routes like `https://myapp.mydomain.com/aaa` are showing this ERROR: `Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0):

Update the content of .htaccess file in the root folder with this. It should work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but after I replaced my code with your code and try to go to my homepage `https://myapp.mydomain.com`, the browser will show this ERROR: `Missing index page or access denied!`

Do You know why?

Comment: there is a server.php file in the root folder, rename it to index.php and there is one index.php file in the public folder also. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/structure